# Propulsion method for MANPADS missiles

Tags: missiles, rocket

What propulsion method is used for small short range handheld missile systems? Liquid fuel rocket engines are the gold standard but I suspect require too many components for the size requirements.

Is it solid fuel rockets or is there some other method? Looking at the outside it doesn't look like they have a turbine or air intake.

Comment: In order not to burn operator the missile must accelerate to (or close to) cruise speed before the tail leaves the tube. Only a solid booster can burn this fast. Had you picked another propulsion, then the missile must a two-stage.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Missiles like a LAWS or Stinger use solid rocket motors.

Despite liquid fuel being preferred for space launchers, for a MANPADS type missile the combination of storability, inertness in transport, low toxicity, and near-zero setup time, along with the very limited performance requirement (compared to longer range missiles) make solid propellant virtually universal.

Don't forget, these missiles are closer, size, weight and performance wise, to a High Power model rocket than to even an SRBM -- and much larger missiles (like the long-running Sidewinder) use solid propellant for the same reasons.  Unlike models, however, these missiles are steerable -- various ones either have seeker heads (like the Sidewinder, too large for shoulder launching, but still solid propellant and small by missile standards), or are wire or radio guided.  Steering is accomplished either aerodynamically, with movable fins (like the Sidewinder), or by thrust vectoring with either a gimballed nozzle or jet vanes (the last is technology that goes back to the 1940s on the A-4 and Wasserfall).

While solid propellant rockets aren't practical to throttle, missiles typically don't care beyond a timed thrust profile to facilitate operator safety -- typically "big push to exit launcher, short idle to provide standoff from the operator, then cruise thrust".  They're then expected to remain under near constant thrust until warhead detonation (or self destruction on a miss).

Some, of course, like an RPG, or WWII bazooka, aren't steered at all; rather, they're aimed like a gun.

Liquid fuels that can be stored and launched on short notice are very toxic (hydrazine derivatives and nitrogen oxides, either of which will kill you quickly).  Those that are less toxic require much more infrastructure, as they almost universally use liquid oxygen (which has to be kept a lot colder than dry ice), and that has to be filled immediately before launch -- and has its own hazards.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. One thing though, my understanding is that solid rocket engines do not allow for thrust control, it seems like this would be a problem.

Comment: Throttling, no, vectoring, yes, via gimbaled nozzle or jet vanes.  I'll edit in.

Comment: You can put steering vanes right behind the nozzle in the exhaust flow and it wouldn't matter if it was a solid rocket motor.  The V2 was steered that way.

Comment: @JohnK Yep, 3rd paragraph, "A-4 and Wasserfall" -- V-2 was the Allied propaganda name for the A-4.  Redstone used the same method as A-4 -- jet vanes coupled with movable fin sections.

Comment: Ah yes that's right.  I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @FourierFlux Partially true. While solid rocket motors can't be throttled in flight, the thrust profile over time _can_ be controlled by changing how the propellant is arranged inside the combustion chamber during production.

Comment: The main reason to use solid rocket motors is storage. These things are (and must be) designed to sit on shelves for years and then must function at the press of a button. Reading [Ignition!](http://www.sciencemadness.org/library/books/ignition.pdf) will tell you how hard this would be with liquid rocket fuel.

Comment: That’s a great book for sure, @PeterKämpf. And on the subject of thrust control, missiles at this range don’t need much thrust *level* control besides “go” once they’re out of the launcher and a safe distance away, and the low altitude gives multiple options for steering.

Comment: @FourierFlux: FYI, Joe Barnard of BPS.Space just did a video on throttling of solid (model) rocket motors: https://youtu.be/8sksiYfkses In the video, he also mentions some additional mechanisms to the one he his presenting that work, but not on the small scale of a model rocket (and the small budget of an amateur rocketeer).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I've seen that video, hence "aren't practical" vs. "impossible" in my answer above.  And as noted, for small missiles, all that's really needed is a high-low-cruise thrust profile which can be shaped into the propellant grain.

Comment: Another, unusual way to steer, is to have rows of charges along the body of the missile, directing some of their thrust sideways. By sequencing which charges on which side of the missile are fired, it can be steered. When it flies it makes a sound like Pop, Pop, Pop, Pop, ..., as each charge goes off.

Comment: @GlenYates And if you steer too wildly, you lose the ability to steer in that plane.  Seems I've seen demos of this in development for kinetic kill antimissile and antisatellite missiles, don't know of it ever being even proposed for environments where fins can do the job.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Yet this was the method used by the FGM-47 Dragon ATGM. It was retired from US service in 2001, but is still in use by several countries.

Comment: @GlenYates Seeker head, rather than operator steered, I'm guessing.

Comment: One thing missing from this answer, is that many systems use compressed gas to throw the missile 20m or so from the launcher before the engine is ignited. This protects the operator from the exhaust if launched from a confined space and helps to prevent giving the operators exact location away.

Comment: @GlenYates That isn't really directly answering the question -- those missiles still use solid propellant rocket motors.

Comment: An explosion (say from a grenade or bomb), @GlenYates, isn't going to care _too_ much about missing by 20m. Grenades, maybe, but if the targeted fighter has a chance to pop off one missile or bomb and gets within 20 meters, it's curtains for the guy who launched from the ground.

Comment: To add to the earlier answers Juan Browne recently posted a video on YouTube in which he explains that the Javelin Anti Tank Missile uses a two stage **solid rocket motor**. One is for launch and the second for flight and the two phases of flight are clearly visible: [Javelin Overview video](https://youtu.be/8CSwXT-y1oE)

Comment: Why would you even want to throttle such a missile?  The missile has to be able to stand up to the thrust of the first stage (burns very quickly so it's done by the time the missile leaves the tube), there's no reason to use a lower acceleration for the second stage.  Once the booster is spent it coasts until either it hits it's target or decides it has failed and self-destructs.

Answer (score 15):

Most shoulder-fired missiles, whether anti-tank or anti-aircraft, are actually two-stage rockets. The first stage is a very fast-burning motor, designed to burn out before the missile exits the launch tube. There is then a short delay, designed to get the missile some distance away from the launcher before the much larger main stage motor fires. The back-blast from a main motor can be 15-20 feet, definitely not healthy for the operator. High speed video of a launch will show the missile popping out and maybe even dropping a foot or two vertically before the main stage fires.